# Serial Smart Card Readers

Tags: smart-card

I have a smart card that is used with a Respironics CPAP machine.  I need to read the data off of the card.  I have the Windows software for the card but I don't have a card reader just yet.  Many people say you need a specific MAKO DT3500 card reader which costs 60-160.00.   In the manual it says that you don't need a driver if you use a serial smart card reader.  My question is: Are serial smart card readers able to access data on most any/every smart card out there?  Is it like a SD memory card reader where pretty much anyone I buy will be able to read the card?  Is that the same for the USB versions?  If I buy a newer USB reader and load the drivers that came with it, will the Respironics software be able to see it.  I know this might be hard to answer but in the experience of the smart card users out there do you generally need a specific card reader for a specific card?

Comment: Here's a picture of a [Respironics smartcard](http://web.archive.org/web/20120614033344/http://www.cpapsupplyusa.com/Respironics-SmartCard-Replacement-10003304.aspx) (Internet Archive link) [Edited by a moderator to add a working Internet Archive link, after the original link died.]

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what type of smart card that you are trying to read.
Is it a  mifare card iso 14443 or ISO 7816 iso.  It should confrm to a standard of the card type (the beauty of standards)  The card is made up of different sectors that you can read and write to and a card identity number.  Some sectors are private and need an access code.  So if you have a card writer you can set these sectors as you wish and add your own access code.  A serial read of the card should send back the card number binary which then needs to be converted into hex or decimal.
If I have a 26bit card reader for a 32bit card then it will not read all of the bits of the card id.  Then also you will need to mask if the reader starts reading at the second bit and where it finishes. Does that make it a bit clearer.  Find what sort of card it is first then go from there. Good luck

Warren

Comment: Other than the name "Respironics" There is nothing else on the card at all. No numbers or letters of any sort.  Can you recommend a smart card reader that "Might" read this card, or which card reader would you buy if you were trying to buy one that stands the most chance of reading a lot of different cards.  I guess I will just try that and look at as a learning experience.  If that stands a chance at working. Thank you very much.
Russ